# uniq, how to be accent insensitive?

Tags: shell, uniq

How to make the shell "uniq"  command accent insensitive?

```
# more test
a
à
b


# LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8  uniq test
a
à
b
```

Expected:

```
# LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8  uniq test
a
b
```

Note: following is not OK, as it would change input data:

```
 cat test | sed "s/à/a/" | uniq
```

Comment: Find a locale that defines such a collation. If there isn't one (I don't think there is), see [Specify the sort order with LC_COLLATE so lowercase is before uppercase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361021/60565) and the question linked in that answer for details on making a custom locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your simple example:

```
$ cat letters.txt
a
à
b
$ paste <(iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//translit letters.txt) letters.txt | sort -s -k1,1 -u | cut -f2
a
b
```

It requires the GNU version of `iconv` to support transliteration to the output encoding, and a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that supports `<(command)` redirection.

Comment: @JoJo It preserves the original text.

Comment: On macOS it would be `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac letters.txt | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit//ignore`, which first converts to UTF-8 NFD then removes the pure diacritics characters. If don't do it that way then for example `ä` would be transliterated to `"a`